# Unwanted red lines when the unwind segue is performed

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, unwind-segue, xcode10.1

I have a view controller, embedded in a navigation controller, which has a button and connects me with **another** view controller with a button. I have ctrl dragged from the button of the **second** view controller to the exit in the Storyboard creating an ***unwind segue***. While the ***unwind segue*** works as wanted (When I click the button it **removes** the current view controller and gets me to the **first** view controller) but once that happens my current view has some *red lines* for no apparent reason. Why does this happen? Has to do with my Xcode installation or does it have to do with Xcode in general?[image: red lines in my view]

I have Xcode 10.1 and although there is nothing fancy in my code here it is anyway:

```
import UIKit

class PresentedViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBAction func myUnwindAction(unwindSegue: UIStoryboardSegue)
    {
        print("You learned to use unwindSegue")
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you added constraints for your buttons?  Do you have any constraints warnings or errors in your storyboard?

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer! I have no warnings or errors in my storyboard. If you replicate exactly what I did in your Xcode, do you get those red lines too?

Comment: Have you tried running this on an actual device?

Comment: I see artifacts like this in the simulator all of the time. I think it's due to the scaling of the simulator. A real device is very unlikely to show the same results.

Comment: I haven't tried running it on an actual device no